# Show that $0$ is a limit point of $L^-$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I need to show that $0$ is a limit point of $L^-$, the set of negative numbers in a real number line.

Given the definition:

> If $M$ is a point set and $x$ is a point, then $x$ is a limit point of $M$ if every open interval containing $x$ contains a point of $M$ different from $x$.

I'm really lost on this. The best I can figure is that $M=(a,b)$ and $a<0<b$, but that really doesn't help explain how $0$ is a limit point in $L^-$. If $L^-$ is a set of negative numbers, how can $0$ be a limit point? In the interval $(a,b)$, wouldn't b always be positive if the interval contains $0$?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, any open interval around $0$ is of the type $(a,b)$ for $a<0<b$ In particular, $\frac{a}{2}$ is negative and is in this interval. The fact that it contains positive integers as well is not relevant in the definition of a limit point.

Comment: 0 is contained within (a,b), so it is a limit point; I understand that. But if $L^-$ does not contain 0, how is 0 a limit point? I am starting to think I am confusing $M$ as a point set with $M$ as an interval. Does this mean that the interval is arbitrary as long as $M$ is contained within it?

Comment: The fact that $0$ is in $(a,b)$ has nothing to do with it being a limit point of $L^{-}$. In fact, in your definition, it states this fact, (a point other than $x$ itself). The intuitive idea of a limit point of a set is that you can get arbitrarily close to the limit point with points from your set. In particular, you can get arbitrarily close to zero from the negative real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

We have $L^-$ which is $x\in\mathbb{R},x\lt0$. $L^-$ translates to $M$ in your definition. Now any **open** interval that contains $0$ must contain an element of $L^-$ that is **not** $0$. Hence $0$ is a limit point of $L^-%$.